# django didn't return HttpResponse Object

Tags: python, django, web

I saw many answers about this subject of HttpResponse object in Django, but i can't resolve it.
Normally, the user enters the information and the database is saved.
But this is not happening since I get this error. Is there that can help?

```
def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0):
    current_user = request.user

    # If the cart count is less than or equal to 0, then redirect back to shop
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()
    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect("store")

    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0
    for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity
        quantity += cart_item.quantity
    tax = (2 * total) / 100
    grand_total = total + tax

    # ---

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Store all the billing information inside Order table
            data = Order()
            data.user = current_user
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            data.phone = form.cleaned_data["phone"]
            data.email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data["address_line_1"]
            data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data["address_line_2"]
            data.country = form.cleaned_data["country"]
            data.state = form.cleaned_data["state"]
            data.city = form.cleaned_data["city"]
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data["order_note"]
            data.order_total = grand_total
            data.tax = tax
            data.ip = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
            data.save()
            # Generate order number
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%d"))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%m"))
            d = datetime.date(yr, mt, dt)
            current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")  # 20210305
            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()
            return redirect("store")
    else:
        return redirect("checkout")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two branches with three outcomes in your code.

- if method == POST:

  - YES: if form is valid:

    - YES: do things, return redirect
    - ELSE: do nothing (fall through)
  - ELSE: return redirect to checkout

The problem is the case where you POST the form but it is not valid; in that case you fall through the other else branch and end up returning `None`, which is naturally not valid.

The simple fix is to unwrap the last `else` so you always redirect back to checkout if there was no success:

```
if request.method == "POST":
   if form.is_valid():
       # ...
       return ...
return ...
```

It would be better and simpler to use a FormView to properly process the data and show form errors to the user.